# paintitem and indexoutofbounds error

Tags: java, swt, runtime-error

I have create a table with bars which shows frequency of the words in a text.I show the number of special word which user click on them or frequency of whole words in the text. I fetch my list of list and send it to the fill table function. All thing is OK but when I select a special word and then click to show whole words I get indexoutofbounds exception. I guess it is because I change my datasource. It is really strange but simple. However, I could not solve it.

```
public void fill_count_table(List<RootWordSet> source){
    final List<RootWordSet> mysource=source;
    if(source!=null){
        for(int i=0;i<source.size();i++){
            TableItem ti=new TableItem(count_table, SWT.NONE);
            ti.setText(source.get(i).getRoot());
        }

        count_table.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                if (event.index == 1) {
                    try{
                    GC gc = event.gc;
                    TableItem item = (TableItem)event.item;
                    int index = count_table.indexOf(item);
                    System.out.println(mysource.size());
                    int percent = mysource.get(index).getWordNumber();
                    org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color foreground = gc.getForeground();
                    org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color background = gc.getBackground();
                    gc.setForeground(Display_1.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
                    gc.setBackground(Display_1.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE));
                    int width = (tc2.getWidth() - 1) * percent / 100;
                    gc.fillGradientRectangle(event.x, event.y, width, event.height, true);                  
                    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(event.x, event.y, width-1, event.height-1);
                    gc.drawRectangle(rect2);
                    gc.setForeground(Display_1.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
                    String text = Integer.toString(percent) ;
                    Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);                 
                    int offset = Math.max(0, (event.height - size.y) / 2);
                    gc.drawText(text, event.x+2, event.y+offset, true);
                    gc.setForeground(background);
                    gc.setBackground(foreground);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
    else{
        count_table.removeAll();
        count_table.redraw();
    }
}
```

this is the line that make error: int percent = mysource.get(index).getWordNumber();
I really do not know what happens when I change datasources. when I shift to each other it stuck. Even I put a println to check the size of datasource but it was quite strange it had two size. One belong to former datasource and one belong to newwr. Anyway If I remove this graphic part table fill correctly. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
int percent = mysource.get(index).getWordNumber();
```

to

```
int percent = mysource.get(index-1).getWordNumber();
```